# Value error: The truth value of array is ambigous

Tags: numpy, matlab, valueerror, cumsum

I am trying to translate the following code from matlab:

```
a=rand;
    i=1;
    while a > cumsum(T_a(Index_a(end,1),1:i))
        i=i+1;
    end
```

Where T_a is a 15x15 array and Index_a is a 51x1 double.
My python attempt is:

```
a=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    i=1
    while a > np.cumsum(T_a[Index_a[-1,0],(0,i-1)]):
        i=i+1
```

I seem to get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8plPW.png)

Comment: Please include the full actual error trace and copyable example data. The indentation of the python code is not valid.

Comment: And please don’t paste images of text, copy-paste the actual text into your post instead. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, `if b`, for an array `b`, is true if all its elements are true. Thus,

```matlab
while a > cumsum(T_a(Index_a(end,1),1:i))
```

is the same as

```matlab
while all(a > cumsum(T_a(Index_a(end,1),1:i)))
```

so you can translate this to Python as

```py
while np.all(a > np.cumsum(T_a[Index_a[-1,0],(0,i-1)])):
```

---

But do note that, **if `T_a` is non-negative**, this can be simplified, because the first element of the `cumsum` result will be the smallest one, and equal to the first element of its input. So you’d need to compare only against that element:

```matlab
while a > T_a(Index_a(end,1),1)
```